# How to order values in column in dataframe based on values of another column in same dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to order values, as ascending, in a column on a dataframe, based on values of another column in the same dataframe. First thing i am doing is to perform a 'select' query to retrieve all data from our table and store it in a dataframe named 'df':

```
def from_econtable_search_virk():
    engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{server}:5432/{database}')
    df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from {table}', con=engine)
```

When i print the dataframe df, i receive an output looking like the following:

```
     number   name        address         city           token
0    1        Alarm       oxstreet 12     Reading        eng
1    3        Center      examstreet 24   Bristol        JOC
2    2        Computer    pentaroad 4     Oxford         eng
3    3        Music       thisstreet 2    London         eng
4    4        School      schoolroad 45   London         eng
5    1        Hospital    madstreet 24    Manchester     Owx
6    2        Bowling     placestreet 5   Birmingham     Owx
7    1        Hotel       cemstreet 24    Liverpool      JOC
8    2        Paintball   shootstreet 2   Manchester     JOC
9    4        Computer    comproad 24     Brigthon       JOC
```

What i then need to do with the dataframe df, is to first and foremost, sort the tokens based on a list (not alphabetically).

`list = ['eng', 'Owx', 'JOC']`

Which should make the dataframe df look like the following:

```
     number   name        address         city           token
0    1        Alarm       oxstreet 12     Reading        eng
1    2        Computer    pentaroad 4     Oxford         eng
2    3        Music       thisstreet 2    London         eng
3    4        School      schoolroad 45   London         eng
4    1        Hospital    madstreet 24    Manchester     Owx
5    2        Bowling     placestreet 5   Birmingham     Owx
6    1        Hotel       cemstreet 24    Liverpool      JOC
7    2        Paintball   shootstreet 2   Manchester     JOC
8    4        Computer    comproad 24     Brigthon       JOC
9    3        Center      examstreet 24   Bristol        JOC
```

Finally, the values in the number column must be ordered in an ascending manner, based on the token, and the dataframe will eventually then look like the following:

```
     number   name        address         city           token
0    1        Alarm       oxstreet 12     Reading        eng
1    2        Computer    pentaroad 4     Oxford         eng
2    3        Music       thisstreet 2    London         eng
3    4        School      schoolroad 45   London         eng
4    1        Hospital    madstreet 24    Manchester     Owx
5    2        Bowling     placestreet 5   Birmingham     Owx
6    1        Hotel       cemstreet 24    Liverpool      JOC
7    2        Paintball   shootstreet 2   Manchester     JOC
8    3        Center      examstreet 24   Bristol        JOC
9    4        Computer    comproad 24     Brigthon       JOC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `token` column to categorical dtype and sort values by `token` then by `number`.

```
cats = ['eng', 'Owx', 'JOC']
df['token'] = df['token'].astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(cats, ordered=True))
```

```
>>> df['token'].dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['eng', 'Owx', 'JOC'], ordered=True)

>>> df.sort_values(['token', 'number'])
   number       name        address        city token
0       1      Alarm    oxstreet 12     Reading   eng
2       2   Computer    pentaroad 4      Oxford   eng
3       3      Music   thisstreet 2      London   eng
4       4     School  schoolroad 45      London   eng
5       1   Hospital   madstreet 24  Manchester   Owx
6       2    Bowling  placestreet 5  Birmingham   Owx
7       1      Hotel   cemstreet 24   Liverpool   JOC
8       2  Paintball  shootstreet 2  Manchester   JOC
1       3     Center  examstreet 24     Bristol   JOC
9       4   Computer    comproad 24    Brigthon   JOC
```

Comment: replace `df.sort_values('token')` with `df.sort_values(['token','number'])` for the final requirement.